# Adding ComboBox in ListView in MVVM following Josh Smith's Article

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox, viewmodel

I have recently started developing WPF Applications using MVVM. I am following [Josh Smith's article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). I have written a basic screen which simply displays the data in a ListView from the ViewModel's ObservableCollection class.  It's a `List<string>`. I just simply want to be able to display the List of strings and than be able to save it back in underlying Property of Parent collection.

Should I be using RelativeSource to link with ViewModel as DataContext?

Here's ViewModel Code.

```cs
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<string> AndOrList
    {
        get 
        {
            List<string> andOrList = new List<string> { "AND", "OR" };
            return andOrList;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<BusObjects.Criterion> Criteria
    {
        get
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<BusObjects.Criterion>(_stream.ParseFilterCriteria().Criterias);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the problem Area

```
<GridViewColumn Header="And / Or">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AndOrList}">
                                </ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
```

Here's the whole XAML Code. I am trying to bind the AndOrList collection to ComboBox.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:FilterCriteriaConverter x:Key="FilterCriteriaConverter"/>

    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CriteriaList"
                          Source="{Binding Path=Criteria}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="DimName" Direction="Ascending"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

    <Style x:Key="CriteriaItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1" />
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEEEE" />
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<DockPanel>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView 
              Name="lstCriteria"
              Grid.Row="0"
              AlternationCount="2" 
              DataContext="{StaticResource CriteriaList}" 
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CriteriaItemStyle}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Rectangle Fill="SteelBlue" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="And / Or">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AndOrList}">
                                </ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DimName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Oprator" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Operator}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DimValue}" />

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" CornerRadius="4" BorderThickness="1">
            <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                  Height="3"
                  Background="SteelBlue"/>
        </Border>                
        <Border Name="xmlBorder" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="4" BorderThickness="1" >
            <StackPanel x:Name="stkPanel" Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <XMLViewer:Viewer x:Name="xmlViewer" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                <TextBox x:Name="txtXml" TextChanged="XmlTextChanged" Visibility="Hidden"
                         Text="{Binding Path=FilterCriteria, 
                            Converter={StaticResource FilterCriteriaConverter}}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Thanks

Pak

Comment: Semantic note: "Criteria" is already pluralized: the singular form is "criterion". Hence - for example - `ObservableCollection<BusObjects.Criteria> Criterias` should be `ObservableCollection<BusObjects.Criterion> Criteria`...

Comment: Thanks, I'll fix that in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just go up to where the `DataContext` is still the view-model, changing the path to `DataContext.AndOrList` and adding a `RelativeSource` finding the respective control.

Further i would not change the DataContext of the ListView, just put everything in the ItemsSource binding:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CriteriaList}}" ...>
```

Then the following should work and the traveral is minimal:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.AndOrList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}">
```

Comment: Hi H.B., Thanks for the reply. I removed DataContext from ListView opening tag and have replaced it as per your suggestion and when I am trying to set the markup for Combobox as you have suggested like this `<ComboBox
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.AndOrList, 
                                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"/>` but getting following error **AncestorType must be specified for RelativeSource in FindAncestor mode.**

Comment: With that exact code you just posted i do not get any errors as the `AncestorMode` is specified. (The `FindAncestor` is superfluous by the way, when setting the AncestorType the mode is set implicitly, so i'd just leave it out)

Comment: ok, I just had to do a ReBuild of the solution and that Error vanished. And I can see the Items in the dropdown. So I sure am marking this as an answer. But I still am struggling to update the underlying Property (Critarion.AndOr) from the value which is being selected in combobox.

Comment: There are quite a few questions about how ComboBoxes should be bound, in your case you probably want to bind the `SelectedItem` to one of the properties on your data-object which is the DataContext, e.g. `SelectedItem="{Binding AndOr}"`.

Comment: Yep, that did it. :) Thank you very much for bearing with my novice questions.